# Why the # (hashes) in Dapper sample

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm just reading this sample from the Dapper "manual":

```
connection.Execute(@"
  set nocount on 
  create table #t(i int) 
  set nocount off 
  insert #t 
  select @a a union all select @b 
  set nocount on 
  drop table #t", new {a=1, b=2 })
   .IsEqualTo(2);
```

Are the #t's a special syntax for something? Or are they just there to confuse me? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `#` means something important in TSQL - a table named `foo` is permenant, for that db/schema. A table named `#foo` is a temporary table - it only exists *for that connection*, and is removed when the connection is closed or reset. A table named `##foo` is a *global* temporary table, and exists everywhere, but is intended to be temporary. This is mainly used when bulk-shifting data.

The use of `#t` here is so that the table only exists on that connection, so we can re-run the test trivially.

Also, a table named `@foo` is either a *table-variable*, or a *table-valued-parameter*, and only exists for that command / sproc.

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborate answer!